# Can't upload Template List

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, custom-list, list-template

I've just created a SharePoint site and am trying to import list templates from a different site, however when trying to upload them I get a permission error:

[image: Permission Error]

Thing is I don't know what permission I'm missing, I already have full control:

[image: System Account with Full Control]

And am a Site Collection Administrator on the base site:

[image: Site Collection Administrator]

What permission am I missing? And how do I assign it to myself?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you encounter this issue in the server or online?

Please check your permission for the list template library.

If in the SharePoint Online, you should enable customize scripts by using PowerShell.

Here's PowerShell for you.

```
#Parameters
$TenantAdminURL= "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com"
$SiteURL= "your site collection URL"

#Connect to Tenant Admin
Connect-PnPOnline $TenantAdminURL -UseWebLogin

#Get the Tenant Site Object
$Site = Get-PnPTenantSite -Url $SiteURL

#Enable Custom Scripting by turning OFF Deny Flag
$Site.DenyAddAndCustomizePages = "Disabled"
$Site.Update()
$Site.Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Reference:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/12/how-to-enable-custom-script-in-sharepoint-online.html#ixzz6Y0ZOWt61